# Nested checkbox/radio in channel form

Tags: safecracker, checkbox

Is it possible to nest manually constructed checkbox/radio.. Check my code..

```
 {options:source_de_revenu}
                {if option_value == 'autre'}
                <div class="small-12 large-6 column">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="check-more" name="source_de_revenu[]" value="{option_value}" {checked}>
                    <label style="margin-right:4px">{option_name} :</label>
                    <label for="sr_autre_nom" class="more-infos inline-input" style="{if sr_autre_nom == '' }display: none{/if}">Spécifier :
                        <input type="text" class="inline-input" name="sr_autre_nom" id="sr_autre_nom" value="{sr_autre_nom}">
                    </label>
                </div>
                {if:elseif option_value == 'ae'}
                <div class="small-12 large-6 column">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="source_de_revenu[]" value="{option_value} " {checked} class="check-more checkbox-group">
                    <label>{option_name} </label>
                    <div class="more-infos">
                        <blockquote> {options:sr_ae_contrainte}
                            <input value="{option_value}//// HERE OPTION VALUE IS NOT THE "nested value /////" type="radio" class="radio-group" name="sr_ae_contrainte" {checked}>
                            <label>{option_name}//// HERE OPTION NAME IS NOT THE "nested name /////</label>
                            <br>
                            {/options:sr_ae_contrainte} </blockquote>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {if:else}
                <div class="small-12 large-6 column">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="source_de_revenu[]" value="{option_value}" {checked}>
                    <label> {option_name}</label>
                </div>
                {/if}
                {/options:source_de_revenu}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by enabling PHP (Outpout parsing) and adding the manually constructed radio OUTSIDE the other tag like so

```
<?php $s_ae = '{options:sr_ae_contrainte}<input value="{option_value}" type="radio" class="radio-group" name="sr_ae_contrainte" value="{option_value}" {checked} ><label>{option_name}</label><br> {/options:sr_ae_contrainte}';
                ?>

            {options:source_de_revenu}
            {if option_value == 'autre'}
            // SOME CODE
            {if:elseif option_value == 'ae'}
            <div class="small-12 large-6 column">
                <input type="checkbox" name="source_de_revenu[]" value="{option_value}" {checked} class="check-more checkbox-group">
                <label>{option_name}</label>
                <div class="more-infos">
                    <blockquote> <?php echo $s_ae; ?> </blockquote>
                </div>
            </div>

            {if:else}
            <div class="small-12 large-6 column">
                <input type="checkbox" name="source_de_revenu[]" value="{option_value}" {checked}>
                <label> {option_name}</label>
            </div>
            {/if}
            {/options:source_de_revenu}
```

Comment: You could rather use stash..